Finding the Generalized Ellipse to a Tangent and the Intersecting Point under Contraints
Given a line
$g: 0 = I - sX_1 - X_2$
$I, s \in R$
I need to find $V$ for an arbitrary $I$ so that there exists a point $(X_1, X_2)$ where $g_I$ is tangent to the ellipse
$V: V = X_1^2A+X_1X_2B+X_2^2C+X_1D-X_2E+F$
$A, B, C, D, E, F \in R$

More intuitively I need to find one of the concentric ellipses shown here with a solid line, so that an arbitrary line shown here dashed touches the line g and where it does so.
I have tried:
with $ V' = V+I-F$, $D' = D+s$ and $E' = E+1$ it can be shown that from g and V follows
$\implies V' = X_1^2A+X_1X_2B+X_2^2C+X_1D'-X_2E'$
Which is also an ellipse. Wikipedia provides the determinant of that ellipse which is zero when there is exactly one solution$(X_1, X_2) \in R^2$. From that follows
$V = F - \frac{B(D+s)(E+1)+a(E+1)^2+C(D+s)^2}{B^2-4AC} - I$
For the example shown this is off by about two orders of magnitude, specifically because s is two orders of magnitude larger than anything else in the central term.

Given an ellipse and a line as
$$
\cases{
\mathscr{E}_f\to a x^2+b x y + c y^2+ d x + e y + f=0\\
\mathscr{L}\to \iota - s x- y = 0
}
$$
determine $f$ such that $\mathscr{E}_f$ and $\mathscr{L}$ are tangent. At the intersection we have that $\mathscr{E}_f$ and $\mathscr{L}$ have common $y$ then after substituting $y$ in both equations we have
$$
p(x) = a x^2+2 b \iota  x-2 b s x^2+c \iota ^2-2 c \iota  s x+c s^2 x^2+dx+e \iota -e s x+f = k(x-x_1)^2,\ \ \ \forall x
$$
which means that at tangency, $p(x)$ has a double root. Grouping coefficients this is equivalent to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 c \iota ^2-k x_1^2+e \iota +f & = & 0\\
 b \iota -2 c \iota  s+2 k x_1+d-e s & = & 0 \\
 a-b s+c s^2-k & = & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and solving for $\{k, x_1, f\}$ we obtain
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 k&=&a-b s+c s^2 \\
 x_1&=&\frac{b \iota -2 c \iota  s+d-e s}{2 \left(b s-a-c s^2\right)} \\
 f&=&\frac{b^2 \iota ^2+2 b d \iota +2 b e \iota  s-4 c d \iota s+d^2-2 d e s+e^2 s^2-4 a c \iota ^2-4 a e \iota}{4 \left(a-b s+c s^2\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Example: Given $\{a=2,b=1,c=3,d=1,e=-1,\iota=1,s=-1\}$ we obtain $\{f = \frac {1}{24}, x_1 = -\frac{7}{12}\}$


First of all, I love you, second of all will approve after verifying answer. I tried that exact approach but did not get that solution.
